Neighborhood of a point can get smaller and smaller?
Lemma
Let $I$ be a time interval, and for each $t ∈ I$ suppose we have two statements, a “hypothesis” $H(t)$ and a “conclusion” $C(t)$. Suppose we can verify the following four assertions:
a. If $H(t)$ is true for some time $t \in I$, then
$C(t)$ is also true for that time $t$.
b. If $C(t)$ is true for some $t \in I$, then $H(t')$ is true for all $t' \in I$ in a neighbourhood of $t$.
c. If $t_{1}, t_{2}, . . .$ is a sequence of times in $I$ which converges to another time $t \in I$, and $C(t_{n})$ is true for all $n$, then $C(t)$ is true.
d. (Base case) $H(t)$ is true for at least one time $t \in I$.
Then $C(t)$ is true for all $t \in I$.

Building our Intuition:
Let $I = [a,b]$, and let's start with the base case,there is $t_{0} \in [a,b]$ where $H(t_{0})$ is true. But by (a.) we must have also $C(t_{0})$ is true. Then by (b.) there is a neighborhood of $t_{0}$, $(t_{1}, t_{2})$ with $t_{0}$ in it, where $H(t)$ is true for all $t \in (t_{1}, t_{2})$. Again by (b.), $C(t)$ is also true in $(t_{1}, t_{2})$. Then by $(c.)$, at the boundaries $C(t_{1})$ and $C(t_{2})$ are also true. Now we have $C(t)$ is true on $[t_{1}, t_{2}] \subset I$. Then we start over using assertion (b.) to get a neighboroohd on each of both end points $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ where $H(t)$ is true, and then use (a.) again so that $C(t)$ is true there, and then use (c.) again so that we get $C(t)$ is true on $[t_{3}, t_{4}] \supset [t_{1}, t_{2}]$.
It seems that we can continue this expansion process over and over again continuously so that $C(t)$ is true on $I = [a,b]$.
Question:
In the assertion $(b.)$, is not it possible that the neighborhood gets smaller and smaller so that the interval in which $C(t)$ is true will never expand to $[a,b]$?

It seems like what you're looking for is real induction; Pete Clark's notes on this (http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/instructors_guide_2017.pdf) may be of interest.

Note you'll need to use some property specific to real numbers. For example, your proposition is true for intervals of real numbers but is not true for intervals of rational numbers.

The set where $C$ is true is open by (b) but also closed by (c). Since any interval is connected, the set is the whole interval.
See, instead of playing cat-and-mouse with this procedure of adding one more interval like Zeno with his paradox, you can state that the set of points where $C$ is true has a supremum. If that supremum is less than $b$ it would be a contradiction right away.
